# Fully isolated Python environment

Tags: python, virtualenv, pyenv

Right now I am using `virtualenv` for my applications deployed in production.

I am running my apps like

```
cd $PROJECT_DIR
venv/bin/gunicorn -c gunicorn.conf.py my_app.wsgi:application
```

or

```
cd $PROJECT_DIR
venv/bin/celery worker --app=my_app.celery_tasks
```

Recently we have migrated to Python 3. The most recent Python 3.6 wasn't available for Ubuntu 14.04, so I compiled it by myself. Compiling it also allows me to benefit from optimizations using [`./configure --enable-optimizations`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41405728/).

So I am thinking about always compiling Python by myself in my deployments. But at the same time keeping `virtualenv` file structure, so that the commands I am using for running apps in my virtual environment would remain the same.

I've seen people recommending using `pyenv`, but what I don't like about it is that it stores the Python itself in `~/.penv` and, apparently, I need to fiddle with `PATH` environment variables to make my commands work in Cron and shell scripts, which I don't like. I'd like to keep all my environment in one directory if possible.

So my question is, can I somehow compile Python into `venv` directory in my project directory, so that the directory structure would be the same as when using `virtualenv`? Like:

```
$PROJECT_DIR/
    my_app/
    venv/
        bin/
            python
            python3.6
            celery
            gunicorn
            ...
        lib/
            python3.6/
                site-packages/
                    celery/
                    gunicorn/
                    ...
```

Comment: Afaik you can't do that. If you want such isolation, use Docker.

Comment: I am quite sure it's possible. And not complicated. Just need some insights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify Python binary when creating the virutalenv:

```
virtualenv env -p /path/to/compiled/python3.6
```